# Issue in action call after IActionFilter OnActionExecuting function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, onactionexecuting

I am using IActionFilter OnActionExecuting function for some security check, but when it calls it check a condition and if that conditions fails i want to redirect it to login action but the problem is, it call the next action as well which i donot want to execute if that conditions is fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
public class MyCustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (someCondition)
        {
            var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
                action = "index",
                controller = "login"
            });
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Make sure your attribute derives from [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx).

Comment: +1 Thanks that works. My mistake is that im not overriding it like base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

Comment: If request is ajax based then its not redirecting to that page instead its opening it in the window